Can I use MSSQL's Failover Partner parameter without configuring database mirroring?
I have 2 MSSQL databases that are not part of the same cluster but they are synchronized manually (without database mirroring configured)
I want my client applications to try connecting to the first DB host. if it fails, it should connect to the second DB host.
I created a connection string (in Java) that looks like this :
        String connectionString = "jdbc:sqlserver://<IP_ADDRESS_SERVER_1>:1433;"
            + "database=<DB_NAME>;"
            + "user=<USERNAME>;"
            + "password=<PASSWORD>;"
            + "encrypt=true;"
            + "trustServerCertificate=true;"
            + "failoverPartner=<IP_ADDRESS_SERVER_2>:1433;";

It connects correctly to the primary DB instance. but if I shut it down and the connection is redirected to the second DB instance the connection is blocked. (connecting this instance as primary works)
Does the redirected connection rely on mirroring?

Why not set up mirroring?  Or even better, an Availability Group?

@HannahVernon, because these 2 servers are in distinct places, the synchronization has already been done manually.


Does the redirected connection rely on mirroring?

Yes and no. The long and the short of it is the driver does various checks, if it doesn't get the right information from the server (because mirroring isn't setup or it isn't hitting some little known functionality with AGs) then the driver will throw an error that mirroring isn't setup.
You could edit the java driver as it is open source and change this behavior, compile it, and then use that in your environment... or as suggested in the comments, use an already available and proven architecture to implement your high availability.
